# Guardar un valor de una caja de texto y pasarlo a otra funcion

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo 3 funciones
Suma
Resta
Resultado
Lo que quiero hacer es guardar el resultado de la función suma y pasarlo a la función resultado.
por ejemplo

```
Valor_incial=5000
def resta():
    Dinero1=stringVar()
    txt2=Entry(root2,textvariable=Dinero1)
    Dinero1.get(str(Valor_inicial - float(Dinero1.get())))
def Suma():
    Dinero2=stringVar()
    txt2=Entry(root2,textvariable=Dinero2)
    Dinero2.get(str(Valor_inicial - float(Dinero1.get())))
def resultado():
DINERO=StringVar()
    txt1=Entry(root4,textvariable=Valor_inicial)
    resultadoN=StringVar()
    DINERO.set(Valor_incial)
```

El codigo esta dentro de una funcion ya que va a ir concatenada con otro codigo

```
def Atm():
DINERO1=5000


#Consultar dinero
def Consulta():
    rootP.iconify() #minimizar
    DINERO1= Retiro()
    def salir():
        root4.destroy()
        rootP.deiconify()#Maximizar

    root4 = tk.Toplevel()  
    root4.title(" "*20 +"Consultar")
    root4.geometry("700x600")
    root4.resizable(False,False)
    fondo = PhotoImage(file="Consulta.png")
    lblFondo = Label(root4, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=5)
    root4.iconbitmap('dinero.ico')
    DINERO=StringVar()
    txt1=Entry(root4,textvariable=DINERO, background="#9a6696", fg="#ffffff").place(x=300,y=310,width=140, height=30)
    resultadoN=StringVar()
    DINERO.set(DINERO1) 
    img = PhotoImage(file="flecha.png")
    BTAA2=Button(root4,command= lambda :[salir()],text="Regresar", width=100, height=100,image=img,justify="right").place(x=570,y=470)

    root4.mainloop()
    
  #El menu para ingresar (retirar o depositar)  
def Ingre():
    rootP.iconify() #minimizar
    def salir1():
        root.destroy()
        rootP.deiconify()#Maximizar
    #Retirar dinero
    def Retiro():
    
        root.iconify() #minimizar
        def ret():
            #BARRACON.set(DINERO_JOSE)
            #Dinero1.set (DINERO1)
            Dinero1.set("" + str(float(Dinero1.get()) - DINERO1))
            messagebox.showwarning ("Finalizado"," Retiro realizado")

        def limpiar():
            resultadoN.set("  ")
    
        def salir():
            root2.destroy()
            root.deiconify()

        root2 = tk.Toplevel()  
        root2.title(" "*20 +"Retirar")
        root2.geometry("700x600")
        root2.resizable(False,False)
        fondo = PhotoImage(file="Retiro.png")
        lblFondo = Label(root2, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=5)
        root2.iconbitmap('tarjeta2.ico')

        Dinero1=StringVar()
        txt2=Entry(root2,textvariable=Dinero1, background="#9a6696", fg="#ffffff").place(x=300,y=310,width=140, height=30)
        
        DTN22=Button(root2,command= lambda :[ret(),limpiar()],text="Retirar", padx=30, pady=30, background="#FFFFFF").place(x=450,y=300)

        img = PhotoImage(file="flecha.png")
        BTAA2=Button(root2,command= lambda :[salir()],text="Regresar", width=100, height=100,image=img,justify="right").place(x=570,y=470)

        root2.mainloop()
        return Dinero1

#Depositar dinero
    def Depo():
        root.iconify()
        def ON():
            resultadoN.set("" + str(float(resultadoN.get()) + DINERO))  
            messagebox.showwarning ("Finalizado"," Deposito realizado")

        def limpiar():
            resultadoN.set("  ")
    
        def salir():
            root1.destroy()
            root.deiconify()
        
        root1 = tk.Toplevel()  
        root1.title(" "*20 +"Depositar")
        root1.geometry("700x600")
        root1.resizable(False,False)
        fondo = PhotoImage(file="Deposito.png")
        lblFondo = Label(root1, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=5)
        root1.iconbitmap('tarjeta1.ico')

        resultadoN=StringVar()
        resN=Entry(root1,textvariable=resultadoN, background="#9a6696", fg="#ffffff").place(x=300,y=310,width=140, height=30)
        
        DTN21=Button(root1,command= lambda :[ON(),limpiar()],text="Depositar", padx=30, pady=30, background="#FFFFFF").place(x=450,y=300)
        img = PhotoImage(file="flecha.png")
        BTAA1=Button(root1,command= lambda :[salir()],text="Regresar", width=100, height=100,image=img,justify="right").place(x=570,y=470)
    
        root1.mainloop()


    #La ventana donde se abrira el menu de ingresar
    root = tk.Toplevel()  
    root.title(" "*20 +"Ingresar")
    root.geometry("700x600")
    root.resizable(False,False)
    fondo = PhotoImage(file="Ingresar.png")
    lblFondo = Label(root, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=5)
    root.iconbitmap('cajero.ico')

    DTN1=Button(root,command=Depo,text="Depositar", padx=30, pady=30, background="#c35b73", fg="#ffffff").place(x=450,y=300)
    DTN2=Button(root,command=Retiro,text="Retirar", padx=30, pady=30, background="#7072ba", fg="#ffffff").place(x=150,y=300)
    img = PhotoImage(file="flecha.png")
    BTAAP=Button(root,command=salir1,text="Regresar", width=100, height=100,image=img,justify="right").place(x=570,y=470)
    root.mainloop()







def salir2():
    rootP.destroy()
#Ventana prncipal donde  esta el meni de consultar o ingresar
    rootP = tk.Toplevel()  
    rootP.title(" "*20 +"ATM")
    rootP.geometry("700x600")
    rootP.resizable(False,False)
    fondo = PhotoImage(file="Opciones.png")
    lblFondo = Label(rootP, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=5)
    rootP.iconbitmap('atm.ico')


    DTN1=Button(rootP,command=Consulta,text="Consultar", padx=30, pady=30, background="#c35b73", fg="#ffffff").place(x=450,y=300)
    DTN2=Button(rootP,command=Ingre,text="Ingresar", padx=30, pady=30, background="#7072ba", fg="#ffffff").place(x=150,y=300)
    img = PhotoImage(file="casa.png")
    BTAAP=Button(rootP,command=salir2,text="Regresar", width=100, height=100,image=img,justify="right").place(x=570,y=470)





    rootP.mainloop()
```

Espero y si puedas entender un poco mas mi código, es un verdadero desastre pero funciona (en su mayoría) solo cuidado tiene imágenes de fondo así como los iconos, las funciones de desglosan asi:

1:Pincipal (opción de ingresar y consultar)
Consultar:
Solo dice tu saldo es: (Ahí es donde debería de ir el resultado)
Ingresar:
Otra función
Depositar:
Solo dice ¿Cuánto deseas depositar? (Ahí es donde hace la suma)
Retirar:
Solo dice ¿Cuánto deseas retirar? (Ahí es donde hace la resta)

Comment: primero cual es tu ventana principal ? segundo los widgets están mal posicionados, tercero esto te funciono alguno ves y por ultimo este código es tuyo ?

Comment: La ventana principal es rootP esta hasta abajo del todo y si funciona, hace "todo" lo que le indique, cierra las ventanas, las minimiza, hace las operaciones y si el código es mío pero me base en los códigos que nos daba nuestro profesor.

Comment: creo que seria mejor usar solo una ventana le metas un frame y al frame le agregas todos los widgets y cada vez que llames a una función destruyes el frame de la ventana y agregas otro frame con nuevos widgets y así te ahorras de crear tantas ventanas.

Answer (score 1):

ok primero tu ventana principal debe ser `Tk()` por que `Toplevel` se usa para una subventana o ventana hija, y si es una ventana principal yo no la metería en una función

segundo si quieres llamar a una función asegúrate que este siempre arriba y no abajo

ahora tu quieres acceder a varias funciones y lo puedes hacer de esta forma, retornando varios valores

```
def funcion():
     ...
     def fun_uno():
        ...
     def fun_dos():
        ...
     def fun_tres():
         ...
        

     return fun_uno, fun_dos, fun_tres
```

y para recibir los valores retornados creas 3 variables ya que estamos retornando 3 valores

```
def Consulta():
    valor_uno, valor_dos, valor_tres  = funcion()
```

cuarto punto no es necesario que le pongas un `mainloop()` a todas tus `Toplevel` solo basta con el `mainloop()` de la ventana principal

Comment: Me sale un error creo que es por que tengo bastantes funciones dentro de otras Gustas que te pase todo mi codigo?

Comment: @aurora_Hernández agrégalo a la pregunta

Comment: Ya esta creo que no me pase ningún detalle.